# Xcode Localization Main.strings file has multiple strings with same context. Link all to one main string?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When enabling localization in Xcode 10, my Main.storyboard automatically created a `Main.strings` file with all the UI Labels and buttons, etc...

I noticed if I have a label named `"Back"` and it's on multiple views, then there are multiple `"Back"` entries in the `Main.strings` file...

Is there a way to link all the multiple `"Back"` entries to only one? So if I change the first `"Back"` it will change all the others?

Original Main.strings file:

```
"FqV-sU-ghM.title" = "Back";
"IOD-zC-S1P.title" = "Back";
"J2c-1j-gzi.title" = "Back";
```

Looking for something like:

```
    //MAIN BACK STRING
    "FqV-sU-ghM.title" = "Back";

    //LINKED TO MAIN BACK STRING
    "IOD-zC-S1P.title" = "FqV-sU-ghM.title";
    "J2c-1j-gzi.title" = "FqV-sU-ghM.title";
```

Comment: I'm researching this too. Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Well first i don't recommend doing anything in the `Main.Strings` file but instead make a new file `.Strings` format and make a key and value and use it for all the labels instead, `Main.Strings` as far as i know should never be modified because it could cause a crash in your app, if a key is missing or something its too risky.

A better solution.

1- Create localization file

2- Create a key for the `back` String, example `"MyButton = "Back";`

3- use the same `Key` for all the `UILabel` you need like this

```
NSLocalizedString("MyButton", comment: "")
```

i would also recommend this article [here](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881).

Comment: Why don't you recommend doing anything in Main.strings? Even the tutorial link you provided explains that you have to modify the Main.strings file for any Storyboard titles, buttons, etc.... I already have a localization.strings file for my .swift code files but this is strictly a Storyboard question

Comment: i don't recommend because it could cause a problems, if something is messed up but ofc you can modify it after all its a file

Comment: i just wanted to provide a solution on how i would do it, and wanted to help, hope i helped in something